# Animating the color of the HTML Progress Element

Tags: html, css, css-animations, progress

I'm attempting to make an experience bar for an html text-based rpg using the `progress` tag in html5, using css keyframes I've tried to alternate its colors between limegreen and yellowgreen, but to no avail. Do keyframes even work with the `progress` tag? Or do I need to us another method?

```css
@keyframes xpbarIE {
  0%{color:limegreen}
  50%{color:yellowgreen}
  100%{color:limegreen}
}

@-webkit-keyframes xpbar {
  0%{background-color:limegreen}
  50%{background-color:yellowgreen}
  100%{background-color:limegreen}
}

progress {
  /*run the color animation in IE*/
  animation-name:xpbarIE;
  animation-duration:.5s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  /*default styles*/
  color:limegreen;
  appearance: none;
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-radius: 25vh;
  
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  border-radius:25vh;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  /*run the color animation for literally anything other than internet explorer and firefox*/
  -webkit-animation-name:xpbar;
  -webkit-animation-duration:.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  /*default styles*/
  background-color: limegreen;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-top-left-radius:12.5vh;
  border-bottom-left-radius:12.5vh;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  /*animation for mozilla*/
  -moz-animation-name:xpbar;
  -moz-animation-duration:.5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  /*default styles*/
  background-color: limegreen;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 25vh;  
}
```

```html
<progress value="50" max="100">XP</progress></li>
```

Comment: Your code actually works, what is the problem?

Comment: Hey, my mind is absolutely blown, I copy pasted this from a site I'm working on where this code is absolutely NOT working. It's wild that it works here but not there. Sorry for causing any confusion.